# Why do we need the host name again when downloading the webpage by using telnet?

Tags: http, hostname, telnet

I learned you could use telnet to download a webpage(making http request), like

```
telnet www.example.com 80
GET HTTP / HTTP/1.1
HOST: www.example.com
```

then the output would be an html source page or something.

My question is if we had specified www.example.com when initializing the telnet request in

```
telnet www.example.com 80
```

why do we still need to specify that again in

```
HOST: www.example.com
```

?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`telnet` has no understanding of HTTP, so all `telnet example.com 80` does is open a connection to `example.com` on port `80`. The subsequent HTTP request is entirely up to you, and that includes the headers.

Without the `Host` header, your request will go to the default virtualhost on the server handling `example.com` (as if you'd typed in the IP address of the server in a browser), which may *not* be `example.com`.